# "The name that you entered is not valid" error with Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to run a simple VBScript example (not an Excel macro) and have run into the *The name that you entered is not valid* issue.

The name has an underscore, no spaces, and the workbook is brand new (the Name Manager shows nothing). Also, although most web examples show := that is a syntax error for me.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

'This line fails
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name="_myRange", RefersTo="Sheet1!$A$1:$D$3"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In normal excel VBA I use`Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$D$3").Name = "_myRange"` will this work in VBscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name:="_myRange"`syntax is the named arguments syntax. As you observed right, you cannot use this with `VBScript`. But then you cannot simply change it to `Name="_myRange"`. `Name="_myRange"` will result in FALSE and so you are trying to use FALSE as a name. Thats why the error.

You must put the arguments in their right order without naming them.

`objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "_myRange", "=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$3"`

Oh and the reference must begin with `=`.

Answer (score -1):

You sure your syntax is correct?
If you refer to the parameters by name, you have to add :=

Try this: call objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add ("_myRange","Sheet1!$A$1:$D$3")

Comment: If you add `:=` to the named parameter syntax in vbscript you will get an error. Named Parameters just aren't a thing in vbscript like they are in vba.