# Expected Statement error when using multiple parameters in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I am working on making a simple vbs that will open and close an excel file and save as it closes. This is to update the values inside the excel file after they are modified by a separate python script, and I need to do it this way for many dumb reasons outside my control.

I don't have a lot of experience with VBS but what I researched about this, I don't see the error in my code. However, I get an error whenever I try to run the code below. There error is:

```
 Line: 7
 Char: 39
 Error: Expected statement
 Code: 800A0400
 Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if(fso.FileExists("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Templates\testfile.xlsx")) then
    set xlapp = createobject("Excel.Application")
    xlapp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Templates\testfile.xlsx"
    xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Templates\testfile_test.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, ConflictResolution:=2
    xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
end if
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb Script on excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428050/vb-script-on-excel) and has been answered multiple times before, just need to search beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standalone VBS, the following lines won't work because VBS isn't VBA. VBA supports Named Argument Syntax in function calls whereas its not supported by VBS

```
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Templates\testfile_test.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, ConflictResolution:=2
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

You have to provide the arguments to the function. So `Function ArgName:=ArgValue` becomes `Function ArgValue`

```
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Templates\testfile_test.xlsx",51,,,,,,2
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close True
```

Comment: @PankajJaju I don't know, maybe it's because it's a 20+ year old language and you think named arguments syntax [hasn't been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22429018/692942) before? You could flag as a duplicate and help keep the place tidy, instead of regurgitating existing answers.

Comment: If 20 years is the base then why even have this forum then - all questions that anyone can ask must have been answered already. It was answered before doesn't mean that my answer was incorrect or against the rules of this forum. I didn't saw the duplicate and answered it. Now that we know its a dup, we can flag the question to close it. But downvoting without leaving a comment is bit of a dodgy move.

Comment: @PankajJaju which means its doing what it should be doing, providing a resource for programmers to get answers to specific problems. Just happens this specific problem was answered years ago and people don't bother to search. Found these duplicates in Google in less than 2 mins. [Here's another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239633/692942).